# Coffeescript mode for node console?

Tags: javascript, node.js, console, coffeescript

I'm wondering if there's any easy way to have an interactive node.js console session do on-the-fly interpretation of commands using coffeescript's syntax.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Assuming you have node.js installed and npm[1], install CoffeeScript with this command:

```
> npm install -g coffee-script
```

Then in your terminal, type:

```
> coffee
```

You will have a node.js-like console, but with CoffeeScript syntax.

[1] To install node.js, download a binary from here: http://nodejs.org/#download

Comment: Is there any way to make an alias for the console, so that i can just run one command from my bash shell and have it start up a console and then run the `coffee` commmand, all in one go?

Comment: Sorry I don't quite follow your question. Do you want a script that will install node.js+coffeescript and will start the console? Otherwise, if you have everything installed, you just run the `coffee` command from your bash(zsh, etc.) shell.

Comment: Ahhh, I see! I misinterpreted your original answer to mean that I should type the `coffee` cmd once a vanilla node console was running.  Accepted.

Answer (score 3):

Just try to type

```
coffee
```

in the shell

**For installation**

1. [Install Node.js First (NPM included)](http://nodejs.org/#download)
2. `sudo npm install -g coffee-script`